# What is the t-sql to see if a table has Page Locking enabled?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running SAP ECC 6.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2.

According to SAP's Early Watch reports I am supposed to disallow Page locking on a few tables in our Production System.

I do not have Early Watch setup in our dev system and wanted to verify that they allowed page locking, before I started running the t-sql to disallow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT allow_page_locks FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('TableName') AND type IN (0,1)
```